# How can i extract data from multiple matching condition?

Tags: talend

I am trying to filter data using below condition in tMap so could you please help me?

`Column1.contains("_A") && Column1.contains("B_") && Column1.contains("CD_") && Column1.contains("_DC")`

Nothing is extracting from database when i use above condition in tMap.

Kr,

R

I am expecting to filter data based on above condition

Comment: I think you want or (||) instead of and

Comment: Thanks for reply

I don't want OR

I want to check all fields in input..if i use OR it will return data from only one condition

Comment: @RajPatil what is the problem you are getting

Comment: show us your tmap and input & output wanted result , so that we can help

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?!?  Using OR makes sense, unless, you're not explaining yourself correctly.  If you want to filter on ANY of those conditions, OR `||` is the way to go.  If some of the statements need to be grouped then you need to specify exactly.  Provide some sample data so we can see.

Comment: I expects all conditions must be true.

Not equal is working for me
(

     (
           !Column1.contains("_A")  
           && 
           !Column1.contains("B_") 
     )
)


I just want to filter data from database where data contains

Column1.contains("_A") && Column1.contains("B_") && Column1.contains("CD_") && Column1.contains("_DC")